# Selector for subsequent sibling of element containing specific item

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a css way to select elements of X type which are after element Y type containing Z type elements?

Given the following html, i could only after the Z type, not after the Y type containing Z.

```css
.y .z:after {
  color: green;
  /* x is not green because it's after y, not z */
}
```

```html
<span class="y">
  y
  <span class "z">
    z
  </span>
</span>
<span class="x">
  x
</span>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

Because there is no method of selecting UP the DOM...*yet*.

There is, under CSS3, [**no parent selector**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) or [**previous sibling selector**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector).

CSS4 offers the [**`:has`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector in which case you would be able to use

```
.y:has( > .z) + .x
```

However, at present, no browsers support this selector.

---

*Note: The `::after` 'element' is, in fact, a pseudo-element, not a selector, used primarily, for styling purposes for inserting "content" **inside** the element to which the `::after` pseudo-element is attached.*

Answer (score 0):

There are two siblings selectors `+` and `~`. The former applies for immediately preceding siblings, the latter for somewhere preceding siblings.

Your example doesn't show siblings, though, just child elements, where no special selector is needed: `.y .z { }`