# Less selector: select sibling, where directly preceding element contains another element with specific class

Tags: html, css, less

given the following structure, is there a way to select `sibling-b` using less?

```html
<div class='sibling-a'>
    <div class='only-if-this-class-is-present'
</div>
<div class='sibling-b'>
</div>
```

As you may gather, I would like to select `sibling-b` whenever `only-if-this-class-is-present` exists on `sibling-a`'s descendant element.

I know CSS does not have a parent selector, and I've looked at answers to questions such as...

[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

[Selector for subsequent sibling of element containing specific item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38791667/selector-for-subsequent-sibling-of-element-containing-specific-item)

... but I'm curious to know if I can select elements this way using Less?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use JavaScript. Less is just CSS.

Comment: Hum, I suspected as much, thank you @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane

Comment: For what its worth, CSS Level 4 draft is trying to get `:has()` pseudo-selector (similar to jQuery's), but no browsers have implemented it yet. https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational

Maybe in the future it can be done with just CSS, but for now you'll have to use JavaScript.